# Can someone share your geth export file with me?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, mining, synchronization

I need to setup an archival node ASAP but the download takes around 1-2 block per second. With this speed it will finish in 2 months (if it doesn't stall, but it does, I have to restart it manually every time).

Can some of you share your (geth) export file for the Main net ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

A fast sync will finished faster than importing a `geth export` file.

An exported blockchain must be processed block by block on your node to build the state trie, whereas a fast sync will build the state try and only fully sync newer blocks. This is much faster than processing the entire chain.

If you have access to an existing node, rsyncing the chaindata would be the fasted method (takes me around 12 hours to rsync a full node on AWS/GCP networks).

Comment: it is going to be an archival node, so I can't use fast sync.